# arcpy.CalculateField_management--Expression Parameter Syntax

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I've created a text field, width 255, called BUFFER in the feature class "ForestRoads_Buffer".  I want to calculate the BUFFER values of all the features to "Y".  The code below doesn't do this and I don't understand what the expression is supposed to look like.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("ForestRoads_Buffer", "BUFFER", "Y", "VB")
```

Comment: Are you working from ArcMap and using "ForestRoads_Buffer" as a layer within the MXD?

Comment: I've run this in the Python window in ArcGIS and get this error message:  "Messages
Executing: CalculateField ForestRoads_Buffer BUFFER Y VB #
Start Time: Tue Jun 06 10:15:36 2017
Empty value for ObjectID = 1
The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 1. For example, the calculated value may be too large for the field or you may be trying to add a string to a number field. This row will not be updated."  I tried running it in PythonWin 2.7.8 as well without success.

Comment: What is "Y"? A feature in another layer? Have you tried making BUFFER a float field?

Comment: "Y" is just supposed to be a string of text, denoting "Yes".

Comment: I believe OPs goal is to have the "BUFFER" field = "Y" for every feature in the FC.

Comment: See Emil Brundage's answer below.  Definitely correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double quotes around the `Y` since it's a string. Try:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("ForestRoads_Buffer", "BUFFER", '"Y"', "VB")
```

Comment: Ah...  Yep that should do it.

Comment: It's trivial but you can leave out "VB"